# Adding a Custom Backend Model to a Custom Attribute

Tags: magento

I am trying to  set a custom backend model for a custom attribute. The problem is that Magento prepends the 'Mage' directory to the path, so I can't keep all the files in my extension directory.

Code:

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_category', $postData['attribute_code'], array(
                        'label'      => $postData['frontend_label'],
                        'input'      => $postData['frontend_input'],
                        'backend'    => 'my_company/myextension_model_category_attribute_backend_file',
                        'required'   => $postData['is_required'],
                        'global'     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'group'      => $postData['attribute_group_name'],
                        'sort_order' => $postData['sort_order']
));
```

Instead of the path being relative to my extension, 'Mage' gets prepended and results in this error:

```
Warning: include(Mage/My_Company/Model/My_Extension/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/File.php): failed to open stream
```

I haven't found a solution that works with the addAttribute() method.

In troubleshooting, it wasn't immediately clear where Magento is prepending the path.

Everything renders fine (I'm using a file renderer), but it doesn't save correctly without the backend of course.

I'm on Magento 1.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check if your app/code/local/Your_Company/Your_Extension/etc/config.xml registered your model to Magento system:

```
<global>
    ...
    <models>
        <my_company>
            <class>Company_Extension_Model_Category_Attribute_Backend_File</class>
        </my_company>
    </models>
    ...
</global>
```

Comment: Close, seems my syntax is off. Changing my config and then my backend to 'company/category_attribute_backend_file', results in a failed to open stream warning for path 'Company/Extension/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/File/Category/Attribute/Backend/File.php'

Comment: OK, putting the backend to 'extension/file' worked. I had to update my class name/path, too. thanks sir.